# How to call different Ajax Calls within the same form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, submit, form-submit

I want to use 2 different Submitbuttons in the same form.
The user should be able to add a file and then do a preview or upload the file.
Each Submit should make a seperate ajax call.

Right now I use the same form twice but thats not the ideal way..

```
 <form method="post" id="import_excel_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <table class="table">
                  <tr>
                    <td width="25%" align="right">Select Excel File</td>
                    <td width="50%"><input type="file" name="import_excel" /></td>
                    <td width="25%"><input type="submit" name="import" id="import" class="btn btn-primary" value="Import" /></td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </form>




<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#import_excel_form').on('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url:"import.php",
      method:"POST",
      data:new FormData(this),
      contentType:false,
      cache:false,
      processData:false,
      beforeSend:function(){
        $('#import').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $('#import').val('Importing...');
      },
      success:function(data)
      {
        $('#message').html(data);
        $('#import_excel_form')[0].reset();
        $('#import').attr('disabled', false);
        $('#import').val('Import');
      }
    })
  });
</script>
```

So the aim is to add a second Submitbutton in the form that refers to an other ajax url (preview.php)
I tried to change the input type in the form to 'button' and the Ajaxcall to .click but that didn´t work.

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

1. You were on the right track, use `click` function and change `submit` with `button`.
2. Don't use `this` in data, you have to use something like `$("#import_excel_form").serialize();`. This is because `this` is valid when you use `on submit` because its point to the current form but, if you change to `click`, its point to current button.

Here is some helpfull code, not tested:

```
<form action="import.php" method="post" id="import_excel_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <table class="table">
                  <tr>
                    <td width="25%" align="right">Select Excel File</td>
                    <td width="50%"><input type="file" name="import_excel" /></td>
                    <td width="25%"><input id="button1" type="button" name="import" id="import" class="btn btn-primary" value="" /></td>
                    <td width="25%"><input id="button2" type="button" name="import" id="import" class="btn btn-primary" value="" /></td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </form>




<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#button1').on('click', function(event){        //  Same on button2
    var form = $("#import_excel_form");

    var url = form.attr('action');      //  Or what you want
    var method = form.attr('method');   //  Or what you want
    var data = form.serialize();        //  Or what you want

    $.ajax({
      url:url,
      method:method,
      data:new FormData(data),          //  Here you cant use 'this'
      contentType:false,
      cache:false,
      processData:false,
      beforeSend:function(){
        $('#import').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $('#import').val('Importing...');
      },
      success:function(data)
      {
        $('#message').html(data);
        form[0].reset();
        $('#import').attr('disabled', false);
        $('#import').val('Import');
      }
    })
  });
</script>
```